# Obtener el valor de un objeto con javascript

Tags: javascript

Quiero que mi funcion myobj devuelva el objeto 'test' con sus values al pasarselo como parametro

```js
    var myVar = { test: { typeA: '501', typeB : '502' } , exam: {typeb:'aaaa', typeb:'orale'}}
        
        function myobj(obj){
            for (const key in myVar) {
          if (obj===myVar[key]) {
           return myVar[key];
          }
        }}
```

Comment: Nos compartes por favor lo que hayas intentado?

Comment: ahi lo cambie por un for , porque no me quedo claro como usar el filter en una function

Comment: No entiendo para que ocupas una función para realizar eso, al final la función lo que hace es acceder ala propiedad `myVar['test']`

Comment: y como seria sin funcion entonces ?

Comment: Acceder a la propiedad `myVar['test']`, te regresara el objeto con sus propiedades  y puedes acceder a por ejemplo `myVar['test'].typeA // "501"`

Comment: claro pero ponele que yo tengo  mas de dos objetos ...,

Comment: por eso creo la funcion para pasarle como parametro el objeto que quiero buscar y que me lo devuelva

Comment: Es que es lo mismo, puedes acceder directamente, la función te serviría si lo que tienes es un Array y ocupas filtrar un registro especifico por alguna propiedad

Comment: Te corregí la función, únicamente tienes que validar por el key, pero sigo con la idea que es mas fácil hacerlo directo.

Comment: gracias, igual  es mas o menos para lo que dijiste la funcion . Es como que tengo un array de objetos, quiero buscar uno en especifico y que me tire sus propiedades

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te añado la solución a tu función, únicamente valida por el key, no el myVar[key].

```js
var myVar = { test: { typeA: '501', typeB : '502' } , exam: {typeb:'aaaa', typeb:'orale'}}
        
function myobj(obj){
  for (const key in myVar) {
    if (obj=== key) {
      return myVar[key];
    }
  }
}

console.log(myobj('test'))
```

Comment: la validación en el if de el for in  `if (obj=== key)`